# Simple elementwise comparison of arrays using operators

Tags: arrays, perl, element

To compare each element of arrays that I know are the same length (and which have a predictable order) in perl we have `each_arrayref` which can be added to useful subroutines or just used directly:

```
use List::AllUtils qw/each_arrayref/;

my ($arr1, $arr2) = ( [10, 31, 12], [20, 21, 14] );

my $iterate_elems = each_arrayref($arr1, $arr2); 
while ( my ($x, $y) = $iterate_elems->() ) { 
   say $x lt $y ? "$x is lower " : "$x is higher" ; 
}
```

or one-lineishly for cut and paste:

```
perl -MList::AllUtils=each_arrayref -E '
  my $iter = each_arrayref([10, 31, 12], [20, 21, 14]); 
  while ( my ($x, $y) = $iter->() ){ 
  say $x lt $y ? "$x lower" : "$x higher"}'
```

But this seems a tad awkward and not completely foolproof. I try to use a descriptive term like `$iterate_elems` as the iterating function reference to help. Perhaps I don't use this enough for it to seem obvious.

In perl6 there are [metaoperators](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Perl_6_Programming/Meta_Operators) which allow for all kinds of fairly succinct and cool list comparisons and munging. This leads me to think there must be a way one could use operator overloading in perl5 to do this. Can anyone comment on the wisdom of this? It seems like it might be easier to understand code written in a way that applies operators to a series of lists instead of iterating through the lists to apply operators. Perhaps creative use of `map` or `List::MoreUtils`'s `apply` would achieve the same thing.

Astonishing perl6 code samples especially welcome.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point of your question, but... If you know the length is the same, what's wrong with `for my $i (0 .. $#array1) { say $array1[$i], $array2[$i]; }` ?

Comment: Normally the array or list would be much larger and one might want to do more more comparisons  of the elements which is what I think `each_arrayref` is supposed to make possible. But yes simpler is better when possible.

Comment: I guess I'm still not getting it. How would an array with more elements, or needing to make more comparisons, change the logic in the loop? Perhaps a more concrete example is in order...

Comment: `$ perl6 -e 'say (10, 31, 12) Zcmp (20, 21, 4 )'` results in `Less More More`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot point well taken - my example is too simple. My understanding of `each_arrayref` (and some other functions in [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) and friends) is that they provide a way of packaging more straightforward constructs like loops so they can be "extended" in different ways: *e.g.* nested `foreach` loops for comparing array elements are clear and familiar, but for three or more arrays, or an array of keys from a hash of arrayrefs *etc.* an `$iterator->()` coderef can save on parens.  ;-)

Comment: For me the `$iterator->()` can make it easier to write comparisons of more than two arrays, or of arrays of different lengths (I'll try to add some examples). But I don't find it ideal and so was wondering about operator overloading or alternatives. As @BradGilbert shows some of the metaoperators in perl6 can make for compact idioms.  `Zcmp` zips together two arrays and does a type-agnostic comparison of the elements as they line up.  `@x Z< @y` would check if elements of `@x` are `<` elements of `@y`, *etc*.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `List::AllUtils`, how about `pairwise`?

```
use List::AllUtils qw(pairwise);

my @arr1 = (10, 31, 12);
my @arr2 = (20, 21, 14);

pairwise { 
    print $a lt $b ? "$a is lower\n" : "$a is higher\n"
} @arr1, @arr2;
```

That fits your problem as stated, and seems simpler to me, but 'simple' is slippery...  Best of luck!